# ¿para que sirve el int opc; en c++?

Tags: c, variables

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
  int opc; // <- porque el termino opc?

  printf( "\n Por favor introduzca un numero del 1 al 7 considerando 1 como lunes " );
  scanf( "%d", &opc );

  switch( opc ) {
  case 1:
    printf( "\n El dia es lunes" );
    break;

  case 2:
    printf( "\n El dia es martes" );
    break;

  case 3:
    printf( "\n El dia es miercoles" );
    break;

  case 4:
    printf( "\n El dia es jueves" );
    break;

  case 5:
    printf( "\n El dia es viernes" );
    break;

  case 6:
    printf( "\n El dia es sabado" );
    break;

  case 7:
    printf( "\n El dia es domingo" );
    break;

  default:
    printf( "\n El numero que has incertado no es el correcto, intenta del numero 1 al 7" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Por cierto, este código no es C++ sino C a secas

Answer (score 2):

A la hora de programar tienes que recurrir más pronto que tarde al uso de variables para almacenar información.

Lo recomendable, para que el programa sea legible (lo que dificulta la aparición de errores y facilita las tareas de depuración y mantenimiento), es que estas variables tengan nombres significativos acerca de su utilidad.

Los nombres son, eso sí, libres en cualquier caso.

```
int opc;
```

En esta línea se está declarando una variable de tipo entero y a esa variable se le ha dado el nombre `opc`. ¿Por qué ese nombre y no otro? Porque es el que ha elegido el que ha escrito el programa... que también podía haber elegido `tengounavaraiblequenosecomonombrar`, pero que lo mismo eligió simplemente `opc` por parecerle lo suficientemente descriptivo.

Answer (score 1):

opc puede ser "opciones". En realidad se declara un numero entero Int y un nombre para esa variable. En scanf se le da un valor a la variable desde el teclado y en switch se compara el valor ingresado. Sino está entre los valores esperados se imprime en pantalla que on es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Observa que *opc* no es una variable global propia de C/C++, ni mucho menos, una función propia del lenguaje. Es el nombre que la persona que escribió el código ha utilizado para referirse a una variable de tipo entero. Tal y como te han explicado, probablemente la llamó así por ser similar a una opción ingresada por teclado.

Comment: @eferion No me he expresado bien, quería referirme a que no es una variable global, ni  propia del lenguaje :(